# How do I use the response from solar.googleapis.com/v1/dataLayers:get in existing map?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-solar-api

I've been using google maps via JavaScript for quite a while. I want to include the solar images (similar to Google Project Sunroof) on my existing map. I am able to pull the data back from solar.googleapis.com/v1/dataLayers:get successfully, but have not figured out how to add it to my map.

I tried adding it like this "map.data.addGeoJson(sunroofGeoJson);" and "map.data.addGeoJson(JsObject.jsify(sunroofGeoJson));", but I keep getting a blank map and this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".

I've been searching the web for 4 hours for an example, but I cannot find anything that ties the response back to the map.

```
var sunroofGeoJson = null;
sunroofGeoJson = await JSON.parse('<%=GetSunroofGeoJson() %>');
map.data.addGeoJson(JsObject.jsify(sunroofGeoJson));
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://github.com/googlemaps-samples/js-solar-potential

Comment: Yes, I started looking at that but it's not very straight forward and more than the basics of what I was hoping to do. I'll be digging into that a little more if I cannot find a simple approach. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, though it is possible to put the data layer response on the Maps Javascript API, the Solar API is not REALLY designed to be used in a web browser, it's more of an API for a desktop program, like QGIS, but it's doable with some extra work to display the GeoTIFF layers on the web. One example you can check out is this. https://blog.nora-soderlund.se/articles/integrating-the-new-solar-api-in-google-maps